# Apt takes a long time just to connect. And keeps disconnecting

Tags: networking, apt, downloads, ping

I just moved back from arch to ubuntu to check in on how it's doing, and when I tried to do `apt-get update`, it took 30 minutes. Then, when I started to do `apt-get upgrade`, it took an hour and only downloaded 10 MiB. I've never seen this before. I've tried changing mirrors, no help.
Thanks for the help. Here's my [server's](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/23424741/) file:

Also, if I ping it, it works as expected:

```
johnsmith@Inspiron-3647:/etc/apt$ ping in.archive.ubuntu.com -c 3
PING in.archive.ubuntu.com (91.189.88.149) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from in.archive.ubuntu.com (91.189.88.149): icmp_seq=1 ttl=50 time=168 ms
64 bytes from in.archive.ubuntu.com (91.189.88.149): icmp_seq=2 ttl=50 time=172 ms
64 bytes from in.archive.ubuntu.com (91.189.88.149): icmp_seq=3 ttl=50 time=171 ms

>--- in.archive.ubuntu.com ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2003ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 168.233/170.696/172.153/1.783 ms
```

Comment: Did you try another mirror?

Comment: Yes I have tried changing mirrors

Comment: Check this: [connecting to archive.ubuntu.com takes too long](//askubuntu.com/q/272796)

Comment: I've tried that. Didn't work